# JS menu with dropdown & slide primary items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a multiple levels menu for responsive HTML.

- Events

  - 2012 Events
  - 2013 Events

    - London
    - Paris
    - New York
  - 2014 Events

    - Berlin
    - Moscow
    - Cape Town
  - 2015 Events
  - 2016 Events
  - 2017 Events

The second level menu i.e. 2012 Events, 2013 Events if there are too many items then they should be sliding items, i.e. there will be Next/Previous arrows.

When I mouse over on 2014 Events then it should open a dropdown menu.

How I can achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use bootstrap multilevel menu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally sorted out solution I wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/rjbd5g3o/1/ here it is.

In this example I am not showing primary items i.e. Home, Events, Leader etc. In the actual project menu items are available as navigation items and when I mouseover on Events then it will open the dropdown vertical menu that I show in http://jsfiddle.net/rjbd5g3o/1/.

```
<section id="introduction">
    <div class="menu_wrapper">
      <div id="example" class="year_menu">
        <div class="slideshow parent" data-visible="4" data-pagination="false">
          <ul class="carousel">
            <li class="slide" id="2013_events"><a href="lead-meetings.html">2013 Events</a></li>
            <li class="slide active" id="2014_events"><a href="lead-meetings-2014.html">2014 Events</a></li>
            <li class="slide" id="2015_events"><a href="lead-meetings-2015.html">2015 Events</a></li>
            <li class="slide" id="2016_events"><a href="javascript:;">2016 Events</a></li>
            <li class="slide" id="2017_events"><a href="javascript:;">2017 Events</a></li>
            <li class="slide" id="2018_events"><a href="javascript:;">2018 Events</a></li>
            <li class="slide" id="2019_events"><a href="javascript:;">2019 Events</a></li>
            <li class="slide" id="2020_events"><a href="javascript:;">2020 Events</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow child" data-visible="4" data-pagination="false">
          <ul class="carousel">
            <li class="slide" id="2013_events_child">
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Belfast</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Dublin</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Manchester</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">London</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Berlin</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Paris</a>
            </li>
            <li class="slide" id="2014_events_child">
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Prague</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Madrid</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Verona</a>
            </li>
            <li class="slide" id="2015_events_child">
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Lyon</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Rotterdam</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Toulouse</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Cork</a>
              <a href="speakers-info.html">Paris</a>
            </li>
            <li class="slide" id="2016_events_child">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="slide" id="2017_events_child">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="slide" id="2018_events_child">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="slide" id="2019_events_child">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="slide" id="2020_events_child">&nbsp;</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Hope my example will be useful for somebody else.

Thanks,
Rakshit Maniar

Answer (score 0):

Try This Responsive Menu

```
<div id="left_container"></div>
<div class="container">
<a class="toggleMenu" href="#">Menu</a>

    <ul class="nav NormalMenu">
        <li class="test">   <a href="#">HOME</a>

        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">LOCATIONS</a>

            <ul >
                <li>    <a href="#">Boroughs</a>

                    <ul >
                        <li>    <a href="#">Enfield</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">E_Locations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">E_Unit Bases</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">E_Parking</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Barnet</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">B-Locations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">B-Unit Bases</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">B-Parking</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#">Maps</a>

                    <ul >
                        <li>    <a href="#">Enfield map</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">ME-Locations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">ME-Unit Bases</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">ME-Parking</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>    <a href="#">Barnet Map</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">MB-Locations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">MB-Unit Bases</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">MB-Parking</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>

        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">LINKS</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="right_container">&nbsp;</div>
```

### [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/9Gf59/7/)

### [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/aGYnU/76/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already have a dropdown menu ready, key point here is to have a sliding on click of prev/next for second level links.